# Is there a simpler proof of Beigel and Tarui's transformaion of ACC0 circuits

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, circuit-complexity

[Beigel and Tarui](http://cvs.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/ryan/acc.pdf)'s transformation of $\mathsf{ACC}^0$ circuits to depth 2 circuits with a polylog symmetric function on top is one of important results in the circuit complexity. For example, the recent breakthrough separation between $\mathsf{NEXP}$  and $\mathsf{ACC}^0$ by Ryan Williams uses this transformation to design a fast $\mathsf{ACC}^0$-CircuitSAT algorithm.

I think the proof in their paper is a little complicated and too technical for me. Is there a simpler proof of their result?

Answer (score 3):

This result is presented in the Web Addendum of Arora-Barak, which can be found [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/uploads/Compbook/accnexp.pdf).